# Fragment :opening activity from fragment giving ActivityNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-fragments, activitynotfoundexception

I am trying to open an `activity` from `Listfragment`  as below

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ((MenuActivity)getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TravellerTimer.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));

    }
```

i registered the `TimeTraveller` activity in manifest file but still its giving `ActivityNotFoundException`

Below is my log trace

```
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.vpiabstest/com.example.activity.TravellerTimer}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:674)
04-19 17:14:00.030: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
```

below is my manifest file

```
< application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".service.ActivityService" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".service.StartupService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="SampleActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MenuTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VpiAbsTestActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.CreateTimer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.EditTimer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.FakeCall"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.ContactList"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.TravellerTimer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity.TimerPrefrence"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

< /application>
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please read your logcat error carefully. It says
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
did you do that?

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` no need to ask

Comment: yes i did registered in manifest    <activity android:name=".TravellerTimer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

Comment: You have written : "i registered the TimeTraveller activity in manifest file but still its giving ActivityNotFoundException". the logcat says com.example.activity.TravellerTimer is not Found. check the Spelling.

Comment: @Santhosh now its gving classcastexception   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.activity.TimerPrefrence
04-19 17:45:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15697):  at com.example.activity.TravellerTimer.onCreate(TravellerTimer.java:48)
04-19 17:45:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15697):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-19 17:45:20.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15697):  at

Comment: post com.example.activity.TravellerTimer.onCreate pls.

Comment: @hari86: class cast exception means you are trying to assign a reference to some other type. for example you might be assigning editText id declared in XML to a textView. paste your TravellerTimer.onCreate() and XML layout file for the same.

Comment: @Santhosh  here are the links to files http://pastebin.com/Pb70fg66   http://pastebin.com/ZnBqQHGG   getting exception at line 47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have registered the Activity with full correct package name in the manifest

Comment: yeah i did it..still same      <activity android:name="com.example.activity.TravellerTimer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

Comment: it seems okay for me .. please check the onCreate of TravellerTimer if there is any problem there

Comment: checked getting classcastexception at this line timerLists = ((TimerPrefrence) getApplication()).viewTimer();

Comment: here are the links to files http://pastebin.com/Pb70fg66   http://pastebin.com/ZnBqQHGG   getting exception at line 47

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28511/discussion-between-stinepike-and-hari86)

Answer (score 0):

Try the current class object using 'this' keyword to call your activity in the intent parameter .

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.Urcurrentactivity, TravellerTimer.class);      this.Urcurrentactivity.startActivity(myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));
```

Your code should also work but by just seeing this quotes, i cant make it sure .

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code in PasteBin:

```
ArrayList<ActiveTimer> timerLists = new ArrayList<ActiveTimer>();
timerLists = ((TimerPrefrence) getApplication()).viewTimer();
```

you are trying to cast TimerPrefrence to an ActiveTimer ArrayList. That is the reason you are getting Class cast exception.